# Slick slider multiple rows rwd

Tags: mobile, slider

Hi I have an issue with my slick slider plugin.
I want to have 4 slides in one (2 rows, 2 slides for row) - in the size > 768px, if I have a width < 768px I want to have one slide. My structure looks like:

```
    <div class="gallery-slider">
      <div class="gallery-box"></div>
      <div class="gallery-box"></div>
      <div class="gallery-box"></div>
      <div class="gallery-box"></div>
      <div class="gallery-box"></div>
      <div class="gallery-box"></div>
     </div>
```

My JS code looks like:

```
$('.gallery-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    rows: 2,
    slidesPerRow: 2,
    responsive: [       
        {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              rows: 1,
              slidesPerRow: 1
            }
        },
    ]
});
```

Why my mobile view not work, 
What can I do in this situation?

Comment: In what way does it not work on mobile, compared with (non mobile?)

Comment: please add a JSFiddle so we can examine your code better